# Microsoft teams bot integration issue while Authenticating: Shows Status as "Requested" on Client side but haven't received

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have bot integration on MS Teams, one of the user integrated my App, in client teams it shows as requested but I haven't received the request on my server. Is it possible to reset the integration completely from client side so that they can retry again or any other options I can try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you developed your bot using teams bot SDK & how are you integration your app in Teams?
Can you please share further information and steps?

Comment: We developed our App using App Studio and published it to Teams

Users can find our app in Apps list of MS teams. When they click on "Add" we get the details of the serviceurl, conversation id etc.. to our servers, after that we send a message template with a button with custom details which will redirect to our website and link it with the login details we have to the teams details

Comment: Can you please ask user to upload the app again and try it once.
If it still doesn't work, please ask user to check the bot logs and see what exact errors are coming.

Comment: Looks like the error is not at Teams bot side. Could you please check if there is some issue at server side? Is any other request are coming to the server?

Comment: Yes got the request of other users in our server side

Comment: There is no option of add the app again from user's side as it shows as requested and can't change it

Comment: Could you please share the bot console log to investigate further?

Comment: Where can I find the bot console log?

Comment: When I try to login for the link you mentioned it is showing this error

Sorry, but we’re having trouble with signing you in.

AADSTS50020: User account 'email' from identity provider 'url' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft' and cannot access the application 'http://GenevaMDM/'(Geneva MDM [wsfed enabled]) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Comment: @SunilChepuri - Can you please ask user to share the Teams browser client error logs ? Check the console error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools

Comment: Also, is this the issue with only Teams Desktop client or he is facing the issue in Teams Web client as well ?